# Initialize an array with implicit size?

Tags: rust

In Rust, is it always necessary to declare the size of an array, even when it's obvious from the initialization what the size should be?

For example:

```
let nums: [i32; 3] = [1, 2, 3];
```

If I decide to edit my code and add `[..., 4]` to the end of that array, why can't the compiler figure out that `nums` is now `[i32; 4]`?

I think what I'm wishing for is something like this (bad notation?):

```
let nums: [i32] = [1, 2, 3]; // does not compile
```